# Alternative to using 'order' within an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, rails-activerecord

I've been doing some edits to an output when working with some records and i've ran into a problem where the sorting option no longer is working.

Initially with how things were created when I would do a `@record.class` the output was `Record::ActiveRecord_Relation < ActiveRecord::Relation`

However now after making my changes the class has changed. So now when I run a `@record.class` the output is `Array < Object`.

I think this is the root reason why i've ran into this problem.

My code is

```
@q = @records.search(params[:q])
@records = @q.result(distinct: true).select { |k,_v| k[:disabled] }
@records = @records.order("records.updated_at desc").page(params[:page] || 1).per(params[:per] || 30)
```

The error I am getting is `NoMethodError: undefined method`order' for #`

Now i've tried to workout around this by

```
@records = @records.sort_by("records.updated_at desc")
@records = @records.paginate.page(params[:page] || 1).per(params[:per] || 30)
```

However the error with the first line of my solution is `@records = @records.sort_by("records.updated_at desc")`  I'm not able to get past that line in case there is an error with my `paginate` solution.

If anyone could take a look, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: It would be useful if you shared where the `search` method is coming from (and if you wrote it, the code).

Comment: What is the reason that you use `select` to select certain records (which loads all record from the database) instead of using `where` and make only load matching records from the database? That would be much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your `@records` is a Ruby array, not an ActiveRecord "array"
You can try `@records.sort_by(&:updated_at)` to sort your array

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are calling `result`, which is causing the SQL query to be executed and data returned from the database. You don't want to do that if you want to continue forming your query using the Arel AST that ActiveRecord uses. You want something closer to this (you'll likely need to adapt):

```
r = records.where(some_param: some_value, disabled: true) \
           .order(updated_at: :desc) \
           .page(params[:page] || 1).per(params[:per] || 30)
```

Answer (score 1):

The signature you the methods you use look like you are using `ransack`.

Instead of loading all records into memory and selecting matching records in Ruby it might be much faster to only load matching records from database in the first place.

Assuming that `disabled` is a boolean column in your database, I would advise to change

```
@q = @records.search(params[:q])
@records = @q.result(distinct: true).select { |k,_v| k[:disabled] }
@records = @records.order("records.updated_at desc").page(params[:page] || 1).per(params[:per] || 30)
```

to

```
@q = @records.where(disabled: true).search(params[:q])
@records = @q.result(distinct: true)
@records = @records.order("records.updated_at desc").page(params[:page] || 1).per(params[:per] || 30)
```

Comment: I really love your concerns with this one, as i have around 9,000 records to work with all together, and it does take a little time to load sometimes `disabled` is a boolean, however when I looked into your approach, I wind up with `undefined method 'where' for #<Ransack::Search:0x007ff9e671fd58>`

Is there a way around this?

Comment: I updated my answer. There where needs to be before all ransack methods in the chain.